# how to abandon special characters and numbers when using re.split with string?

Tags: python, python-re

If I want to split a string with spaces preserved, but don't want to include special characters and numbers.

So it would look like this.

```
sentence = "jak3 love$ $b0x1n%"
list_after_split = ["jak", " ", "love", " ", "bxn"]
```

I want to use `re.split()`, but I am not sure what to write as a pattern.

Comment: Do it in 2 steps: remove the special characters with a regex, then use String's split.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do so with a single `re.split()` since the third word is not split. I would use `re.sub` followed by a simple `re.split()` and since you want the spaces preserved you can add a space every other position of the list. Careful with the `re.sub()` pattern since some symbols need to be escaped.

Comment: If you have `sentence = "Many     spaces  here"`, do you want to preserve the whitespaces? As in output `['Many', '     ', 'spaces', '  ', 'here']` or condense them together into `['Many', ' ', 'spaces', ' ', 'here']`?

Answer (score 3):

Try filtering the unwanted characters out first:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "jak3 love$ $b0x1n%"
>>> sentence_filtered = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]+', '', sentence)
>>> # Alternative: sentence_filtered = ''.join(ch for ch in sentence if ch.isalpha() or ch.isspace())
>>> sentence_filtered
'jak love bxn'
>>> re.split('(\s+)', sentence_filtered)
['jak', ' ', 'love', ' ', 'bxn']
```

Comment: Flipping this logic on its head for demonstration purposes: `[re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', w) for w in re.split(r'(\s+)', sentence)]`

Comment: could you elaborate more on what did you write in the pattern for re.sub() ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to condense whitespaces into a single space:

```
import re

# String with multi-spaces, tab(s), and newline(s).
s='Jak3     \t love$s \n  $D0ax1t3e90r%.'
print(s)
# Jak3         love$s 
#   $D0ax1t3e90r%.

# First, remove all characters which aren't letters or a space.
# Second, condense spaces together into a single space.
# Third, split into desired list.
print(re.split(r'( )', re.sub(r' +',' ',re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]+', '', s))))
# ['Jak', ' ', 'loves', ' ', 'Daxter']
```